# Passing data to highcharts from javascript array or variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts, chart.js

I am converting json to string and saving the content in an arrays.
from the array am directly sending the values to charts js and its working fine.

But its not working in highcharts. What could be the issue?

I have also tried passing variables with data directly to high charts but it isn't working

//converting from json to string and saving in array

```
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("items");
var amnts = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
```

//how i have passed data to charts js & its working correctly

```
data: {
      labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 
              'Sartuday', 'Sunday'],
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Week 1 Income',
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          data: [amnts[0], amnts[1], amnts[2], amnts[3], amnts[4], 
          amnts[5], amnts[6]]
      }
```

//passing data to highcharts & NOT WORKING & not displaying data in chart

```
series: [{name: 'Week 1 Income',
         data: [amnts[0],amnts[1],amnts[2], amnts[3], amnts[4], amnts[5], 
                amnts[6]]
}
```

I expected the array data or a variable passed to show the value in the chart

Comment: You mean when you pass the `data` object to `highchart` it is working correctly and for `series` array it is not?

Comment: @randomSoul Sorry, Its working correctly in charts js data object but not working in high chart series

Comment: You are missing ending brackets `]` in series array for highCharts

Comment: @JoharZaman its in my code but its still not working, I just copied a small part of the code

Comment: If I type values directly in the sr=eries object, it just works fine

Comment: What is inside the `amnts` did you check that?

Comment: It seems like your `data` array in `series` is empty.

Comment: @randomSoul,  but before sending it to series I have printed it on the screen using 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = amnts; 
   And am getting the following output on my screen 10,20,40

Comment: @JoharZaman but before sending it to series I have printed it on the screen using 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = amnts; 
   And am getting the following output on my screen 10,20,40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this I think it works.

```
series: [{name: 'Week 1 Income',
         data: [parseInt(amnts[0]),parseInt(amnts[1]),parseInt(amnts[2]), parseInt(amnts[3]), parseInt(amnts[4]), parseInt(amnts[5]),parseInt(amnts[6])]
}
```